# Windows Explorer start notification

Tags: windows, explorer

Is there an easy way to be notified about start of Windows Explorer. 
The problem is that Explorer sometimes crashes and is restart automatically - but the tray icons has to be added manually again by the programs.

I realize that I can monitor processes and see if Explorer disappears and reappears - but I was wondering whether there perhaps was a Windows message broadcasted when Explorer was up again?

Comment: One problem for that idea with the monitoring is that you would have to check just in between disappearing and reappearing as else......"oh its here it never was gone was it?".  So timing could nullify everything you are trying to accomplish there.   Also one question: As you mention programs are they written in specific programming languages or how are the tray icons added?

Comment: See the TaskbarCreated message documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179.aspx

Comment: Explorer crashing is a sign of a faulty shell extension, bad memory or other trouble. Are you sure you want to support an unstable machine?